# How to invert clipping geometry in Silverlight/WPF?

Tags: .net, silverlight, geometry, clipping, clip

The [`UIElement.Clip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx) property takes a [`Geometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) object and uses it to clip away the outside of the `UIElement`.  I would like to do the geometric inverse and punch a hole into the element instead.

Anyone know how to do this?

I imagine creating an inverted version of the clip geometry would work, but I can't find a way to do this.

---

**EDIT** It seems that WPF has [`Geometry.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607449.aspx) which can be used to subtract one geometry from another, though this isn't available in Silverlight.  If it were, I could subtract the clip geometry from the rectangle of the element's bounding rectangle, and use that to clip instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One approach in Silverlight is to use a `GeometryGroup` and include in the group a very large rectangle starting at a distant negative position.

For example the following blue square has smaller square hole:-

```
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200">
        <Rectangle.Clip>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="-2048 -2048 4096 4096" />
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="100 100 50 50" />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Rectangle.Clip>
    </Rectangle>
```